# Retrieve all elements with matching name from a semi-arbitrary structure

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'll preface by saying that I am not experienced with MongoDB, so I am not even sure where to start.

Here's some sample data.

```
{
   "_id":"59ae56c899620ff94e9baab7",
   "latitude":45.616012,
   "longitude":148.351045,
   "group_a":[
      "culpa",
      {
         "pupils":[
            {
               "id":0,
               "a":{
                  "name":"John Bobbard"
               }
            },
            {
               "id":1,
               "name":"Eva Smith"
            },
            {
               "seniors":[
                  {
                     "id":0,
                     "name":"Trina Bradley"
                  },
                  {
                     "id":1,
                     "b":{
                        "name":"Paul Graham"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "id":2,
                     "c":{
                        "name":"Deirdre Hubbard"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "greeting":"Hello, Janice Atkinson! You have 10 unread messages.",
   "favoriteFruit":"banana"
}
```

My desired output contains names and values of `_id, latitude, longitude`, all `name` fields (i.e. `John Bobbard, Eva Smith, Trina Bradley, Paul Graham, Deirdre Hubbard`), and `greeting, favoriteFruit`. The problem lie in that I have no way to tell how many `name` fields there will be in `group_a` in total, or how many `name` fields there will be in on each "depth" level of `group_a`, where they can be placed semi-arbitrarily. I may have a way to know how many "sublevels" in `group_a` there are, but not necessarily.

My best guess is either that I have misread the documentation on `find`, or that I need to do a separate aggregation query of sorts to extract all `name` from `group`, and then join that with the product of `find` for the rest.

I have searched for similar problems, but all I have seen so far do not address the structural variance present in my problem.

Comment: The so called *structure* you have shown is not useful. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46038686/edit) your question and show us sample document with the expected output. For now I am voting to close as it is unclear what your are asking.

Comment: @sstyvane I have updated the question.